# Overlapping panels

Tags: java, swing, layout

I'm trying to make overlapping panels, but widgets below the 'topmost' panel somehow react to mouse events and repaint events and render above the top layer. For example, here I have bottom layer with lots some buttons and labels, and a top layer with up/down buttons, which is fully opaque for this test (gray background):
[image]
This uses the `OverlayLayout` manager to place panels on different Z levels. The buttons pop into view when hovering over them, and the labels on the right, which auto-update, also pop into view.

SSCCE:

```
public class Temp extends JPanel {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            JFrame f = new JFrame();
            f.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            f.setContentPane(new Temp());

            f.setSize(500, 250);
            f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            f.setVisible(true);
        });
    }

    public Temp() {
        super(null);
        setLayout(new OverlayLayout(this));

        JButton bottom = new JButton("Bottom");
        JButton top    = new JButton("Top");

        bottom.setBounds(100, 50, 200, 100);
        top.setBounds(200, 100, 200, 100);

        // OverlayLayout adds components from top to bottom.
        add(new JPanel(null) {{
                setBackground(new Color(175, 150, 125));
                add(top);
            }});
        add(new JPanel(null) {{
                add(bottom);
            }});
    }
}
```

This is basically how I do it now. It looks like this after a bit of mouse hovering, but with hovering I can bring any of the two buttons above the other:
[image]

My question is, how can I fix this in the easiest way, or what is the standard way to handle this? Perhaps a Non-modal frame-less JDialog? One argument I have against the dialog is I rather not that the user uses keyboard shortcuts to move it around the screen.

Comment: Start by having a look at [How to Use Layered Panes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html)

Comment: Ok, it works; just a slight pita that it has no layout manager, and that it lets mouse events through. It feels like a hack to just add empty mouse adapters to the top panel.

Comment: It's just a container, you can apply a layout manager if you want to. I'm not sure what you mean by your second comment, that's all containers work

Answer (score 0):

> and a top layer with up/down buttons, which is fully opaque for this test (gray background):

It doesn't make sense to have an "opaque" top panel. You will not see the buttons on the bottom panel. The top panel should be transparent and the bottom panel should be your background color.

> My question is, how can I fix this

If you are referring to the fact that the buttons ZOrder keeps changing as you hover over each button then you need to override the following method on your Temp panel (ie. the panel using the `OverlayLayout`):

```
@Override
public boolean isOptimizedDrawingEnabled()
{
    return false;
}
```

This basically says that the Temp panel may contain overlapping components so all panels need to be repainted in the proper ZOrder each time.

Comment: The opaqueness was just for the sake of the test. For the solution I went with the `JLayeredPane` instead, which works great, except for the mouse clickthrough. Any solution for that?

Comment: `The opaqueness was just for the sake of the test.` - well the code and question should reflect what you are actually doing so we don't spend time on a wild goose chase.